# pdftotext can't find any of the files to convert when called within a python script

Tags: python, pdftotext

i have a python script which keeps crashing on:

```
subprocess.call(["pdftotext", pdf_filename])
```

the error being:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

the absolute path to the filename (which i am storing in a log file as i debug) is fine; on the command line, if i type `pdftotext <pdf_filename_goes_here>` it works for any of the alledgedly bad file names. but when called using `subprocess` in python i keep getting that error.

what is going on???

also, i tried on the python interpreter, and it worked!

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(["pdftotext", "/path/to/file/test.pdf"])
0
>>>
```

**update:** just to make it known to everyone, i also tried:

```
subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/pdftotext", "/path/to/file/test.pdf"])
```

which also gave the same error. and ive used `/usr/bin/pdftotext test.pdf` directly and it worked so i know that's the correct path to the pdftotext executable. any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll also get that error if it can't find the executable on path...try using a full path to pdftotext as well, and look at how the $PATH for subprocess.call is set.

Comment: wouldn't this be ruled out since i could get it to work on the python interpreter?

Comment: Are you just inheriting the parent's $PATH? If so then maybe something changes it before the subprocess.call(), which isn't happening when you just do the call from the repl.

Comment: yes, i am. well, implicitly i must be since i'm not doing anything to $PATH knowingly.

Comment: newb unix question time: where is the best place to look for pdftotext, or how should i go about finding it?

Comment: type 'which pdftotext' in the shell to get the full path